# Entity Framework Update Fails for Entity With ID of 0

Tags: entity-framework, temporary

Using Entity Framework Core 3.0 and facing an odd issue where EF will throw an exception if I try to update an entity with ID=0, it thinks that ID=0 is a temporary value. Same code updates entity with ID=1 or higher without any problems.

Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' on entity type 'MyType' has a temporary value
>   while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either
>   set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is
>   configured to generate values for this property.

Exception is triggered on the following statement:

```
_context.Attach(MyType).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I don't want to reseed all my tables to start with 1.

Is this expected behavior with EF? It should be possible to save entities with ID=0.

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *have* to do something about this zero `ID` value. It's a ticking time bomb.

You'll always have to be on your guard because it definitely is expected behaviour. EF has inner logic depending on key default values. In EF6 you could do this because it was less refined. (In *this* area that is).

Let me show you how leaving this ID value can backfire on you in the future.

You have this `MyType` object. Let's call it `entity` to follow some naming conventions/habits. Its ID value is `0` and it's not attached to the context.

Now suppose you don't use this rather redundant way to attach it as modified but the new EF-core way:

```
context.Update(entity);
```

Now you won't see any exception, but no, the issue isn't fixed. It's gotten worse. The `entity` object's state is `Added` now and you're going to add a new record to your table. That might even go unnoticed for a while, adding to the pile of mess you have to clean up later.

Had its `ID` value been `> 0`, EF's `Update` method would have concluded it's an existing entity and its state should be `Modified`.

You *can* set `entity`'s state to `Modified` if (1) it's not attached and (2) you use...

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

And that's another time bomb. Later code changes remove the first condition (it's not attached) and boom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So am I understanding this correctly, does EF expect all entities' IDs to start with 1?

Comment: Not entirely. It infers entities with `ID == 0` (`ID == default(Guid)` etc)  to be new. For the rest you're free to let ID values start where you want. You could even use negative values, although that would be highly uncommon and likely to cause problems in other software stacks.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. I've just truncated and reseeded all tables, all IDs start with 1 now and problem is resolved.